# Ignore IE's Temprorary Internet Files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, internet-explorer, browser-cache

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 application that it's static contents (*.js, *.css etc.) are located in the same server but I want to try to use CDN hosting for them.

Last week I've just changed the links of this static contents (`<link>`, `<script>`, `<img>` 's pointing urls) in aspx files and then published it but I gave lots of feedback these contents are not loading on Internet Explorer 8 without deleting browsing history. So I reverted back the changes and it's normal now.

Is there any possiblity to ignore IE's browser cache mechanism without requesting user to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the top of the page:

```
<% Response.CacheControl = "no-cache" %>
<% Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" %>
<% Response.Expires = -1 %>
```